# How to make CLIPS program work?

Tags: clips

I am new to CLIPS and I thought of looking over existing solved problems for a start and try to figure it backwards. There is the following problem found in Giarratano-Riley: Expert Systems and Programming 3rd edition and it states the following:

> Fires are classified according to the principal burning material.
> Translate the following information to rules for determining fire
> class.
>
> - Type A fires involve ordinary combustibles such as paper, wood, and cloth.
> - Type B fires involve flammable and combustible liquids (such as
>   oil and gas), greases, and similar materials.
> - Type C fires involve energized electrical equipment.
> - Type D fires involve combustible metals such as magnesium, sodium, and potassium.
>   The type of extinguisher that should be used on a fire depends on the fire class.
>   Translate the following information to rules.
> - Class A fires should be extinguished with heat-absorbing or
>   combustion-retarding extinguishers such as water or water-based
>   liquids and dry chemicals.
> - Class B fires should be extinguisher by mexcluding air, inhibiting the release of
>   combustible vapors, or interrupting the combustion chain reaction. Extinguishers
>   include dry chemicals, carbon dioxide, foam, and bromotrifluoromethane.
> - Class C fires should be extinguished with a non conducting agent to prevent
>   short circuits. If possible the power should be cut. Extinguishers
>   include dry chemicals, carbon dioxide, and bromotrifluoromethane.
> - Class D fires should be extinguished with smothering and heat- absorbing chemicals > that do not react with the burning metals. Such chemicals include trimethoxyboroxine
>   and screened graphitized coke.

Describe the facts used in the rules. The input to the program should be made by asserting the type of burning material as a fact. The output should indicate which extinguishers may be used and other actions that should be taken, such as cutting off the power. Show that your program works for one material form each of the fire classes.

And then it is solved by Berkely and the code is the following. My question is, how do I call these rules and make the program work? I loaded the buffer, reset, run and it only loads the rules into the command-line.

```
; Define templates used in rules

(deftemplate fire (slot burning-material))

(deftemplate extinguisher-system (multislot function) (multislot extinguisher))

(deftemplate response (multislot actions))

(deftemplate fire-class (slot class))


; Define rules for determining fire classes

(defrule class-A-fire
(fire (burning-material paper | wood | cloth | other-ordinary-combustibles)) =>
(assert (fire-class (class A))))

(defrule class-B-fire
(fire (burning-material oil | gas | greases | other-flammable-combustible-liquids)) =>
(assert (fire-class (class B))))

(defrule class-C-fire
(fire (burning-material energized-electrical-equipment)) =>
(assert (fire-class (class C))))

(defrule class-D-fire
(fire (burning-material magnesium | sodium | potassium | other-combustible-metals)) =>
(assert (fire-class (class D))))

; Define rules for determining the type of extinguisher that should be used on a fire

(defrule class-A-emergency
(fire-class (class A))
=>
(assert (response (actions activate-extinguisher-A))) 
(assert (extinguisher-system (function heat-absorbing combustion-retarding) (extinguisher water water-based-liquids dry-chemicals))))

(defrule class-B-emergency
(fire-class (class B))
=>
(assert (response (actions activate-extinguisher-B))) 
(assert (extinguisher-system (function excluding-air inhibiting-release-of-combustible-vapors interrupting-combustion-chain-reaction) (extinguisher dry-chemicals carbon-dioxide foam bromotrifluoromethane))))

(defrule class-C-emergency
(fire-class (class C))
=>
(assert (response (actions activate-extinguisher-C power-cut))) 
(assert (extinguisher-system (function nonconducting-agent) (extinguisher dry-chemicals carbon-dioxide bromotrifluoromethoane))))

(defrule class-D-emergency
(fire-class (class D))
=>
(assert (response (actions activate-extinguisher-D))) 
(assert (extinguisher-system (function smothering-heatabsorbing-chemicals) (extinguisher trimethoxyboroxine screened-graphitized-coke))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you made it until here:

```
CLIPS> Loading Selection...
Defining deftemplate: fire
Defining deftemplate: extinguisher-system
Defining deftemplate: response
Defining deftemplate: fire-class
Defining defrule: class-A-fire +j+j
Defining defrule: class-B-fire +j+j
Defining defrule: class-C-fire +j+j
Defining defrule: class-D-fire +j+j
Defining defrule: class-A-emergency +j+j
Defining defrule: class-B-emergency +j+j
Defining defrule: class-C-emergency +j+j
Defining defrule: class-D-emergency +j+j
CLIPS> (reset)
```

Now you need to load the problem data. For example, for a wood fire:

```
CLIPS> (assert (fire (burning-material wood)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (fire (burning-material wood))
```

And the, run the rules engine

```
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (fire (burning-material wood))
f-2     (fire-class (class A))
f-3     (response (actions activate-extinguisher-A))
f-4     (extinguisher-system (function heat-absorbing combustion-retarding) (extinguisher water water-based-liquids dry-chemicals))
```

And clean it to check the next problem

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (fire (burning-material gas)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out too!